# JavaScriptのArray.prototype.map()で複数の配列を操作するには？

Tags: javascript

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [1, 2, 4];
var c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    c[i] = (a[i] == b[i]);
}
```

このような複数の配列の操作を、以下のようなArray.prototype.map()を使って記述するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

```
c = a.map(element => {
    /*なにか*/
});
```

できれば、以下のようなindexは使いたくありません。

```
c = a.map((element, index) => {
　  return element == b[index];
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

map関数は各要素に関数を適用するだけなので、複数の配列を束ねるzip関数を使うことになります。が、残念ながらzip関数はJavaScriptにはありません。

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) や [Prototype.js](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/zip/) に入っているものを使うか、自前で実装するか（[例](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284006/2818869)）、あきらめて他の方法にするか、というところかと思います。

Answer (score 4):

**配列 a の要素がユニークな場合**

```
c = a.map(element => {
  return element == b[a.lastIndexOf(element)]
});
```

同じ要素が複数ある場合には意味がありませんので実用的ではないですね…

**配列 b をコピーしても良い場合**

```
bb = b.concat();
c = a.map(element => {
  r = (element == bb[0])
  bb.shift()
  return r
});
```

`Array.shift()` を実行することで比較対象が常に配列の先頭(`bb[0]`)にある様にしています。

Answer (score 0):

僕の考えでは、あなたの使いたくないというその手が最適だと思います。
いっそ関数にしてしまえば使いやすいのでは?

```
const zipWith = f => xs => ys => 
  xs.length < ys.length ? xs.map((e,i)=>f(e,ys[i])) : ys.map((e,i)=>f(xs[i],e));
const zipEq = zipWith( (x, y) => x === y );

let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [1, 2, 4];    
let c = zipEq(a)(b) //=> [true,true,false]
```